# Find the dimensions of the rectangle that will give the minimum perimeter.

Tags: geometry, maxima-minima

a farmer wants to make a rectangular paddock with an area of $ 4000 m^2$ However, fencing costs are high and she wants the paddock to have a minimum perimeter.

I have found the perimeter:

$$x\cdot y = 4000\\
    y = \frac{4000}{x}$$

$$\begin{align}\text{Perimeter} &= 2x + 2y\\
              &= 2x + 2(4000/x)\\
              &= 2x + (8000/x)\end{align}$$

How do I find the dimensions that will give the minimum perimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just minimize the function that you found for the perimeter. The minimum is attained when the derivative is zero. So calculate:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} perimeter= \frac{d}{dx}(2x+\frac{8000}{x})=2-\frac{8000}{x^2}=0.
\end{equation}
This gives $2=\frac{8000}{x^2}$, so $4000=x^2$. We then get
\begin{equation}
x=\sqrt{4000},
\end{equation}
since the negative solution is not an option.

Comment: A rectangle has two sides longer than the other two. square root of 4000 gives me one answer. if breath and height are the same, it would be a square.

Comment: A shape being a rectangle means that it has 90 degree angles, so a square is just a specific case of a rectangle.

Comment: ok so both x and y are 63.2455...?

Comment: That's true. Since y=4000/x=4000/\sqrt(4000)=\sqrt(4000)

Comment: If fences are sold in integer length, so the size will be 64*63, how can I account this into the formula?

Comment: @Roy In my answer I have used $(x+y)^2=4xy+(x-y)^2$ If the product is fixed, the sum will be minimised if the sides are as close as possible (making $(x-y)^2$ as small as possible).

Answer (score 0):

As $x>0$

by AM GM inequality  $$\dfrac{2x+\dfrac{8000}x}2\ge\sqrt{2x\cdot\dfrac{8000}x}$$

which can also be written as

$$2x+\dfrac{8000}x=\left(\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{\dfrac{8000}x}\right)^2+2\sqrt{2x\cdot\dfrac{8000}x}\ge2\sqrt{2x\cdot\dfrac{8000}x}$$

Comment: @Utsav, Find the last part.  Do you know that for real $a, a^2\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle with maximal area and minimal perimeter is square
if $x\cdot y=4000$ then $x=y$ so $x^2=4000$ and $x=\sqrt{4000}=63,2455...$

Comment: I suspect that the OP wants to treat this with the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2x+2y=p,\, y= p/2 -x ; \, A= y\cdot x =  (p/2 -x)\cdot x $$

$$ \frac{dA}{dx} =0 \rightarrow x = p/4 =y ,\quad A= p^2/16. $$

For maximum area it should be a square of quarter perimeter length as side.

Answer (score 0):

If you use $A.M \geq G.M$, you get $2x + 2y \geq 4\sqrt{xy} = 80\sqrt{10}$ and equality holds iff $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

To minimise $2(x+y)$ subject to $xy=A$ note that: $$(x+y)^2=4xy+(x-y)^2=4A+(x-y)^2$$

Now since $x$ and $y$ are both positive, the minimum value of $2(x+y)$ occurs when $4(x+y)^2$ is a minimum and hence when $(x+y)^2$ is a minimum.

Since $(x-y)^2$ is non-negative, the minimum occurs when $x-y=0$ ie when you have a square and $x+y=2\sqrt A$ and $2(x+y)=4\sqrt A$